# ClickOnce using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, version, increment

I have been trying to achieve ClickOnce deployment using [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) scripts, but I could not find any resource on how to copy the files after generating the manifests.

Since we need to script baby steps in case of mannual deployment, which Visual Studio does for us if we use the wizard, I'm not able to do it, since I'm new to both MSBuild and ClickOnce.

Is there a resource where I can find detailed information on how to script the entire ClickOnce deployment for multiple environments, increment version number using [TeamCity's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity) BUILD_NUMBER and sign the assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you see Visual Studio doing is done by MSBuild (except creating/updating the "publish.html"). This is true for any environment, if you meant configuration. To publish using MSBuild, all I do is execute the following at Command Line:

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.5\msbuild <myProjectName> /p:Configuration=Debug; /t:publish
```

This gives me a Development environment Build (we use the default Debug configuration for Dev). For QA I just replace the "Debug" part in the above command to "Release".

Comment: is there a way to direct the ClickOnce publish output to an http or file svr destination?